# How do I make it so that an absolute child is behind a fixed parent?

Tags: css

I have a fixed header that shows a child when a button is clicked. I made it as hover on the jsfiddle to make it simpler, but if you do so, you can see that the child is on top of the parent. Is there anything I can do to make it show behind instead?

Also, I need the parent to have a `z-index` [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kjL9raLn/)

```css
#parent {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: #fff;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 9;
}
#child {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background: #000;
  position: absolute;
  top: -200px;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  transition: 0.2s;
}
#parent:hover #child {
  top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">Hover me
  <div id="child">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: add your code to the question - it will help other SO users who might have a similar/same question.

Comment: @alexwc_ I think I've already stated the problem clearly on the title.

Comment: yes you have - but seeing what you've already tried really helps. Having a fiddle is good, but having the code on this site ensures it won't disappear (unless you delete it or is voted to be removed).

Comment: @alexwc_ You're right, I'll see what I can do...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have a wrapper around the elements so you can play with the z-index. See below or [view this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/alexwcoleman/s62hz96r/).

```css
#parent {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#child {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background: #000;
  position: absolute;
  top: -200px;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

#parent:hover #child {
  top: 50px;
}

.wrapper {
  z-index:0;
  position:fixed;
  width:100%;
  top:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="parent">Hover me
    <div id="child">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Works great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've been through a similar problem and solved by changing some of the HTML structure and CSS. I hope it helps you.

**Here, I made some updates based on your example**

```css
#parent {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: #f00;
  
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 9;
}

#child {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background: #000;
  
  position: absolute;
  top: -200px;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 8;
  
  transition: 0.2s;
}

#parent:hover ~ #child {
  top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">Hover me</div>
<div id="child"></div>
```